# AJAX.BeginForm PostURL being corrupted

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm experiencing a strange problem while trying to use the Ajax.BeginForm method of ASP.NET MVC3.   The form renders properly on the page with the correct action attribute.  However, when the form is submitted, the "OnFailure" event is returning a "Not Found" 404 error.

If I watch the request with fiddler, I see that the post URL is "/[Object NodeList]" which is obviously invalid.

My Razor code is as follows:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "Items", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "itemContainer", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnFailure = "onFailure"}))
{
    <div style="position:absolute; bottom:20px; left:200px;">
        <button type="submit" id="Save" name="action" value="Save">Save</button>
        <button type="submit" id="Cancel" name="action" value="Cancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I should mention that I'm using the unobtrusive ajax library that contributed to the problem.   Not sure if this is an issue with the "obtrusive" flavor of MVC ajax.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was using "action" for the name attribute on the submit buttons.  As soon as I changed the name attribute to a different value, everything started working perfectly.

I'm guessing that there is a jQuery selector in the unobtrusive ajax library that got confused.

Comment: Thank you! Pounded my head against this same problem for quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have unobtrusive JavaScript on or off in your web.config?  Im first guessing here the ms Ajax library is acting goofy so enable unobtrusive so we get jquery support.

What is your form action set to? Post your form HTML element if you can .

Comment: I found the fix.   It had to do with the name attribute on the submit button.

Comment: the name of the submit button changed the url you were posting too? that sounds so weird!

Comment: I think I agree with @AdamTuliper here changing the name of a button shouldn't change the url you were posting to. If you change it again to something you haven't used before does it break?

Comment: Yes, when using unobtrusive Ajax, and you have a button or input with type='submit' and name='action', it prevents the callback from working properly.   Changing the name attribute to anything but "action" resolves the issue.